# How to make KendoUI grid.setOptions working with MVVM?

Tags: mvvm, kendo-ui, kendo-grid

In latest release kendo introduced ability for [saving grid state and layout](http://demos.telerik.com/kendo-ui/grid/persist-state) which I can't make working with the javascript MVVM declared grid.

My problem can be reproduced by performing few simple steps with bellow given jsfiddle code

1. Resize columns
2. Save the state
3. Move the columns to some other width
4. Load the state

What I would expect to be the outcome is that after step #4, column width will be reset to saved state.
What I see in my repro is that grid.setOptions just reset the grid to initial unmodified state.

Here's the [jsfiddle repro link](http://jsfiddle.net/2h45scge/1/) also given as inline code snippet here...

```js
 $(document).ready(function () {
   var dataSource = new kendo.data.DataSource({
    data: [
      {name: 'John', surname: 'Smith'},
      {name: 'John', surname: 'Doe'}
    ]
  });

    var dataContext = new kendo.data.ObservableObject({
      dataSource: self.remoteDataSource
    });

    var viewTemplate = 
        "<div id='grid' data-role='grid' data-sortable='true' data-editable='true' " +
        "data-resizable='true' data-reorderable='true' data-navigatable='true' " + 
        "data-columns=\"[{'field':'name', 'title':'Name'}, {'field': 'surname', 'title': 'Surname'}]\"" + 
        " data-bind='source: dataSource' />";


    // now get the main view
    var kendoView = new kendo.View(viewTemplate, {
      wrap: false,
      model: dataContext
    });

    kendoView.render($("body"));

     var grid = $("#grid").data("kendoGrid");

    $("#save").click(function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        var options = grid.getOptions();
        console.log(options);
        localStorage["kendo-grid-options"] = kendo.stringify(options);
    });

    $("#load").click(function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        var optionsString = localStorage["kendo-grid-options"];
        if (optionsString) {
            var options= JSON.parse(optionsString);
            console.log(options);
            grid.setOptions(options);
        }
    });

 });
```

```html
<link href="http://cdn.kendostatic.com/2014.3.1119/styles/kendo.common.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<link href="http://cdn.kendostatic.com/2014.3.1119/styles/kendo.metro.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://cdn.kendostatic.com/2014.3.1119/js/kendo.all.min.js"></script>

<body>
    <div class="box">
        <a href="#" class="k-button" id="save">Save State</a>
        <a href="#" class="k-button" id="load">Load State</a>
    </div>
</body>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have just received the answer from Telerik customer support with a working resolution tip

> This weird behavior is coming from the fact that the options are first provided through data-attributes and then the setOptions method of the Grid new options are passed through JavaScript, however the data-attribute options are still on the element and they are still considered options higher priority at this point.
>   As a temporary work-around you can remove the data-attribute that gives the column options and then the new options should be applied.